# Cakephp 3 delete filtering by associated data

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3, suppose I want to delete all **Departments** that have some **Employee** named "John" (*Departments have many Employees, Employees belongs to Department*)

The easiest approach is to filter all those Departments, and delete them one by one in a foreach loop:

```
$departments = $this->Departments->find()
    ->matching('Employees', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Employees.name' => 'John']);
    })
    ->all();

foreach ($departments as $department) {
    $this->Departments->delete($department);
}
```

This will result in one SELECT query plus one DELETE query for each record. I'd prefer one only query to be sent and executed by the database. Something like this:

```
DELETE Departments 
FROM departments Departments 
INNER JOIN employees Employees  ON 
    Employees.department_id = Departments.id 
    AND Employees.name = 'John';
```

Reading the docs I find three ways to delete records:

- [Using the Table object one by one](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html), get the object, then delete it.
- [Using the Table with **deleteAll**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#bulk-deletes), which takes an array of conditions over the target table, not the associated ones.
- [Using the ORM](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-delete-statements), again with only an array of conditions.

Is there an elegant way to obtain my query using CakePHP 3 and the ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

**FIRST: The scenario I suggested is not correct**

My real case is much more complicated, so I made an example with the well known *employee-department* case. I made a mistake: what I need is to **delete all employees that belong to a certain department**. I want to remove data from a table based con conditions on a related table.

Actually, you can't delete departments where there is an employee named John, 'cause the department is not empty, there's John!! :D

Something like this:

```
-- Create structures
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departments (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  department_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY fk_employees_department_idx (department_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

ALTER TABLE employees
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employees_departments FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


-- Populate some data
INSERT INTO departments (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Sales'),
(2, 'TI'),
(3, 'HHRR');

INSERT INTO employees (id, department_id, name) VALUES
(1, 1, 'John'),
(2, 1, 'Mary'),
(3, 2, 'Mark'),
(4, 3, 'Lorenzo');


-- Delete all employees that belong to the TI department (Mark should be removed)
DELETE emp FROM employees emp
INNER JOIN departments dep ON emp.department_id = dep.id AND dep.name = 'TI';
```

**SECOND: You can do this in CakePHP easily**

You can get the same result of the previous query doing this:

```
    $departments = $this->Employees->Departments->find()
        ->select(['Departments.id'])
        ->where(['Departments.name' => 'TI']);
    $this->Employees->deleteAll(['Employees.department_id IN' => $departments]);
```

The resulting mysql query will be:

```
DELETE FROM employees WHERE department_id in 
(SELECT Departments.id AS `Departments__id` 
FROM departments Departments 
WHERE Departments.name = 'TI')
```

...which is correct and moreover easy to understand. @arilia, you pointed in this direction with your first answer. Sorry for the confussion.

Answer (score 0):

deleteAll is just a wrap around

```
$this->Departments->query()
   ->delete()
   ->where([...])
   ->execute();
```

So I though that, in a similar way, it would be possible to do:

```
$departments = $this->Departments->query()
    ->delete()
    ->matching('Employees', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Employees.name' => 'John']);
    })
    ->execute();
```

but in this case you'll notice that the matching condition is ignored. I see that there is an open [**ticket**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8777) about that

If you want to use just two queries you could do a query to retrieve all the ids and the delete all in the second query:

```
$departments_ids = $this->Departments->find()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->matching('Employees', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Employees.name' => 'John']);
    })
    ->toArray();

$this->Departments->deleteAll(['id' => $departments_ids ]);
```

that results in something like:

```
DELETE FROM departments WHERE id IN
(
    // id list here
)
```

another solutions could be transform your inner join in a subquery. Actually you want to delete all the departments that have almost an Employee named John.

```
$employees = $this->Departments->Employees->find()
    ->select(['department_id'])
    ->distinct()
    ->where(['Employees.name' => 'John']);

$departments = $this->Departments->query()
    ->delete()
    ->where(['id IN' => $employees])
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks @arilia. Actually, to obtain that query you should change `'id' => $departments` to `'id IN ' => $departments`, otherwise what you get is an equal condition "=".  In the other hand, that query is returning a [1093 mysql error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).

Comment: Anyway, the resulting SQL query is still wrong according to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) where they say _You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery._

Comment: I did not know about that. I will edit or delete my answer

Comment: Thanks again @arilia. I also tried the first approach, with `delete` and `matching`, but efectively the matching criteria is ignored. Your other solution with the _IN array_ would work. The problem is my actual issue is not about Departments and Employees (it's just an example), and my list of Departments could have thousands records, so I guess It will break the query at some point.

Comment: I'm beginning to think now there's no way to launch my query with Cake, other than hard-coding it. I'm going to reference this question in the issue you have pointed. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can always transform your inner join in a subquery you can use in a where clause